# CORS policy, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in React.JS

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, xmlhttprequest, fetch

Hi guys I know there are many questions about CORS Policy. But I still have not found a solution for my case. I'm creating a page which has online payment features by credit-card. And API was send me by Bank. So I cannot modify server-side. My API is https://sanalpos.bankname.com.tr/servlet/est3Dgate like that. How to solve my CORS policy without server-side. You can see my sample code below.

```
axios.post('https://sanalpos.bankname.com.tr/servlet/est3Dgate', body, 
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"
        }
      })
    .then( async response => {
        responseFromServer = response.data
        console.log(" ~ file: ThreeDPayment.js ~ line 161 ~ SendCreditCardDetails ~ responseFromServer", responseFromServer)
    }).catch( async error => {
        console.log(" ~ file: ThreeDPayment.js ~ line 163 ~ SendCreditCardDetails ~ error", error)
    });
```

[image: Cors Policy Error]

Comment: you need to use CORS package of npm

Answer (score -1):

> How to solve my CORS policy without server-side.

That is not possible without server-side. CORS headers must be set by the server on the HTTP response, *not* by the client on the request as you do.

As sarangkkl already said, your server code must include something like

```js
app.use(require("cors")());
```